# How should I apply flashing to new construction joined to existing brick

Tags: waterproofing, flashing

I am planning to close off a screened in porch with OSB sheathing and vinyl siding.  After framing in the area and attaching OSB to the studs, I plan to apply Tyvek house wrap to help keep water out while also letting water vapor out.

Do I simply use flashing tape where the OSB and house wrap meet brick?  And, then for the bottom layer, to ensure any water drains out, run aluminum flashing sloped away from the sheathing over top of the brick where the screens presently are and underneath the house wrap?  Again, apply a flashing tape where those surfaces meet and run a bead of caulk along those edges as necessary?

Lastly, I will install vinyl siding over top of that which will further help to keep moisture away from the sheathing.

Alternatively, I am considering the zip system which is essentially OSB with the house wrap already on the surface.  Could I then either use zip flashing tape or the zip caulk to seal that edge and keep water out?